# Actualizar totales de tabla filtradas con vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Buen día.

He creado una tabla con datos cuya última columna se totaliza con el método **totalizarVenta** y se muestra al pie de la tabla.
Al aplicar un filtro (mediante un computed **ventasFiltradas**) a esta tabla quisiera que este total al pie de la tabla también se actualice (una vez filtrado se llame automáticamente el método **totalizarVenta** y que sume solo las filas que quedaron luego de aplicar el filtro) y sume solo el contenido de la tabla filtrada, el problema que tengo es que siempre me sale el mismo total. Necesito su ayuda por favor, gracias.

```
<tr>
....
    <td><input type="text" v-model='filtroNombre' class="form-control"></td>
....
</tr>

<tr v-for="(item,index) in ventasFiltradas">
....
   <td class="text-right">@{{ subtotal }}</td>
</tr>


<tr>
....
   <td class="text-right">@{{ ventasTotales.toFixed(2) }}</td>
</tr>


var app = new Vue({
   ....,
           computed: {
                ventasFiltradas: function() {

                    return this.ventas.filter((venta) => venta.nombres.toLowerCase().includes(this.filtroNombre.toLowerCase()));

                },

                ventasTotales: function() {
                    return this.ventas.reduce((total, item) => {
                        return total + parseFloat(item.subtotal);
                    }, 0);
                }, 

                prendasTotales: function() {
                    return this.ventas.reduce((total, item) => {
                        return total + parseInt(item.prendas);
                    }, 0);
                }
   ....,
```

Gracias.

Comment: No conozco mucho Vue.js, pero encontré esto: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uuLmk9o1/)

Comment: Gracias Crisman. He utilizado tu link para mejorar mi código, pero persite mi problema que al filtrar la tabla, los totales no se modifican: \r

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el código entonces? Gracias.

Comment: Edité el código, más limpio, ahora ventasTotales está en computed y calculado de manera más simple, y eliminé en el method la función que hacía la suma de manera más compleja. Pero igual si filtro por nombre la tabla,  ventasTotales no se modifica, permanece con el mismo valor.

Comment: Gracias. Observo que tus métodos obtienen los totales desde una variable llamada `ventas`. Realiza los métodos utilizando `ventasFiltradas`. Pues, en un primer momento `ventasFiltradas` será igual a `ventas` (ya que no tiene ningún filtro) y si se le aplica alguno los métodos calcularán a partir de los items filtrados.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias Crisman, cambiando ventas por ventasFiltradas fue la solución, estuve bastante tiempo buscando la respuesta y era algo tan simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los **métodos** de calculo de los totalizados deben de realizarse en función de la variable que es **afectada** por el filtro (`ventasFiltradas`).